# Google Spreadsheet JSON request - 400 status

Tags: json, google-sheets-api

Hi I have a public google spreadsheet at [Google Docs](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AtEgI2WeGqwBdFZ3SThmdkJ0bEVZd0JYS1hjZjh3M2c#gid=0).  However when i request the JSON with:

```
$.getJSON( "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/0Ak0qDiMLT3XddHlNempadUs1djdkQ0tFLWF6ci1rUUE/od6/public/values?alt=json-in-script&callback=?&gid=0",
function (data) {   console.log(data) })
```

I get a HTTP 400 request error.  Strangely the same exact code works for [this spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Ak0qDiMLT3XddHlNempadUs1djdkQ0tFLWF6ci1rUUE#gid=0).

What's going on here?  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was looking for a solution to the same problem. It led me to this.

Just want to share [the fix](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/):

"Warning: API requests using the public visiblity for feeds on spreadsheets that are not **"Published to the Web"** yield an HTTP 400 Bad Request response with the message The spreadsheet at this URL could not be found. Make sure that you have the right URL and that the owner of the spreadsheet hasn't deleted it."

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, I guess you maybe had forgotten to share it or forgotten to make it public. I just tried it and it is working fine.  By entering this link in a browser:

https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/0Ak0qDiMLT3XddHlNempadUs1djdkQ0tFLWF6ci1rUUE/od6/public/values?alt=json-in-script&gid=0

Comment: Yeah that is the json for the spreadsheet I said was working... Not the one that isn't working.  My spreadsheet is already public. Thanks though.